# How to dm all in discord server

Tags: python, discord

This is my code for discord self bot. It will first check if the token is valid and if it is valid it will then log in to that token. Nothing happens after it login(it is supposed to print status: online ) as per the client.event() on_ready. I think my small command is also broken please help.

```
def Bot_run():
    Token = input("DISCORD TOKEN : ")
    request_url = "https://canary.discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me"

    req = requests.get(request_url, headers={'authorization': Token})
    if req.status_code == 401:
        print(f"The token : {Token} is invalid")
        inv = input("press enter to close")
        exit()
    if req.status_code == 200:
        print(f"The token : {Token} is valid")
        
    client.run((Token),bot=False)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('status : online')

@client.command()
async def dmall(ctx,*,message):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        await ctx.message.delete()
        try:
            await member.send(message)
            print(f'Sent dm to: {member.name}')
        except:
            print(f'failed to send message to {member.name}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do:

```py
...
@client.command(name="dmall")
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def dm_all(ctx, dm):
   for i in ctx.guild.members:
       await i.create_dm() # create a dm with i
       await i.dm_channel.send(dm) # send a message through dm channel
...
```

Corrected Code:

```
import pyautogui , time , sys  , os , colorama , requests ,discord , asyncio
from pathlib import Path 
from os import system
from discord.ext import commands, tasks 
 
#self bot command prefix
 
CEND      = '\33[0m'
CGREEN2  = '\33[92m'
CBLUE   = '\33[34m'
CRED    = '\33[31m'
CYELLOW = '\33[33m'
 
def fivesectimer():
    num = ['5',
           '4',
           '3',
           '2',
           '1']
    
    for i in num:
        sys.stdout.write("\r\x1b[K" + "starting in " + i + " second")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
 
    os.system("cls")
 
def tensectimer():
    num = ['10',
            '9',
            '8',
            '7',
            '6',
            '5',
            '4',
            '3',
            '2',
            '1']
    
    for i in num:
        sys.stdout.write("\r\x1b[K" + "Program is closing in " + i + " second")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
    
    os.system("cls")
 
def normalspam():
 
    print("What do you want to spam ? ")
    word = input(CRED + ">>> " + CEND)
    print("How many time do you want to spam ? ")
    x = int(input(CRED + ">>> " + CEND))
 
    fivesectimer()
 
    for i in range(x):
        pyautogui.typewrite(word)
        pyautogui.press("enter")
 
 
def wordlistspam():
    print("Enter the .txt file name (without .txt)")
    filename = input(CRED + ">>> " + CEND)
    filenames = (filename+".txt")
 
    if Path(filenames).exists():
 
        print("Do you wish to start now ? [ Y / N ]")
        yn = input(CRED + ">>> " + CEND)
        yn = yn.lower()
 
        if yn == ("y"):
            fivesectimer()
 
            f = open(filenames, 'r')
            for i in f:
                pyautogui.typewrite(i)
                pyautogui.press("enter")
 
            fin = input("The task is finish press enter to close")
            exit()
 
        if yn == ("n"):
            tensectimer()
            exit()
        
        else:
            v = input("invalid choice press enter to close")
 
 
    
    if not Path(filenames).exists():
        print(filenames + ".txt do not exist do you want to create new .txt with that name ? [ Y / N ]")
        respond = input(CRED + ">>> " + CEND)
        respond = respond.lower()
 
        if respond == ("y"):
            file = open(filenames ,'w')
            w = input("Please write the wordlist in " + filenames + " and run the program again")
 
            tensectimer()
            exit()
        
        if respond == ("n"):
            c = input("Press enter to close.")
 
def discordwebhookspam():
    x = 0
    WEBHOOK_URL = str(input("Webhook URL : "))
    WEBHOOK_USERNAME = str(input("Name : "))
    WEBHOOK_AVATAR = str(input("Avatarurl : "))
    WEBHOOK_CONTENT = str(input("What to spam : "))
    SPAM = int(input("How many time to spam : "))
    while x < SPAM:
        try:
            payload = {"content":WEBHOOK_CONTENT,"username":WEBHOOK_USERNAME,"avatar_url":WEBHOOK_AVATAR}
            r = requests.post(WEBHOOK_URL,data=payload)
            x +=1
            print(WEBHOOK_CONTENT + "have been sent to webhook")
        except:
            print("Spam failed")
            pass
    os.system("cls")
    print("Spam finished")
 
def Bot_run():
    Token = input("DISCORD TOKEN : ")
    request_url = "https://canary.discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me"
    
 
    req = requests.get(request_url, headers={'authorization': Token})
    if req.status_code == 401:
        print(f"The token : {Token} is invalid")
        inv = input("press enter to close")
        exit()
    if req.status_code == 200:
        print(f"The token : {Token} is valid")
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.r ')
 
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print('status : online')
 
    @client.command(name="dmall")
    async def dm_all(ctx, message):
        for member in ctx.guild.members:
            try:
                await member.create_dm()
                await member.dm_channel.send(message)
                print("Message has been sent to "+ member.name)
            except:
                print("Message failed to sent to "+ member.name)
 
    try:
        client.run(Token, bot=False, reconnect=True)
        print("Login success")
    except discord.errors.LoginFailure:
        print("Unable to connect")
        
 
 
 
def credit():
    print("")
    print("               [*]=----------------------------------------------------------------------------------=[*]")
    print("                |                                                                                      |")
    print("                |                 Discord : REACT#1120                                                 |")                     
    print("                |                 Github : https://github.com/reactxsw                                 |")
    print("                |                 steam : https://steamcommunity.com/id/reactswthegod/                 |")
    print("                |                                                                                      |")
    print("                |                 Discord server invite link :                                         |")
    print("                |                 https://discord.com/invite/R8RYXyB4Cg                                |")
    print("                |                                                                                      |")
    print("               [*]=----------------------------------------------------------------------------------=[*]")
    print("")
    ic = input("")
 
def choice():
    print("               [*]=--------------------------------------------------=[*]")
    print("                |                                                      |")
    print("                |                 1. Normal spambot                    |")                     
    print("                |                 2. Wordlist spambot                  |")
    print("                |                 3. Discord webhook spam              |")
    print("                |                 4. Discord self bot                  |")
    print("                |                 5. Credit                            |")
    print("                |                                                      |")
    print("                |                                                      |")
    print("               [*]=--------------------------------------------------=[*]")
    print("")
    spamchoice = input(CRED + ">>> " + CEND)
    
    if spamchoice == ("1"):
        os.system("cls")
        normalspam()
 
    if spamchoice == ("2"):
        os.system("cls")
        wordlistspam()
    
    if spamchoice == ("3"):
        os.system("cls")
        discordwebhookspam()
    
    if spamchoice == ("4"):
        os.system("cls")
        Bot_run()
    if spamchoice == ("5"):
        os.system("cls")
        credit()
 
 
 
 
choice()
```

Comment: When i run it it didn't print status : online ? is there something wrong with it ?

Comment: It is a snippet: a part of code you are supposed to paste in. Put this code where you put the dm command. Cheers!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/y0WP7d7H here is my full code please help

Comment: @ArdilMc spambots are against the discord TOS and are bannable! Don't use them!

Comment: just making for learning purpose not using them thank btw

Comment: Ok good to know. But don't use spambots. Anyways, replace **your dmall command code** with my **dmall code**. The code is in my answer.

Comment: I don't think it is able to login/ client.run. It is not printing what it is suppose to do @client.event

Comment: I don't see the image :p

Comment: https://imgur.com/3ttiqpI it would be easier if you could contact me through discord React#1120

Comment: Ok. I see your code. But now I'm saying to replace your command (dmall) with my code in my answer. I'll edit the code with the replaced thing.

Comment: no it doesn't work when i do .r dmall message nothing happen at all. it does not even print anything

Comment: I'll look deeper into it, thanks for notifying me

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command(name="dmall")
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def dm_all(ctx, dm):
   for i in ctx.guild.members:
      await i.send("message")
```

you also need the members intent
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html